# How to send my intent to a specific broascastreceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have an intent `i`, when I broadcast that intent via `sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);` Random receivers were being invoked ( i know it is completely normal). I used `queryBroadcastReceivers (Intent intent, int flags)` and found multiple Broadcastreceivers registered. I would like to send my intent to a particular receiver.

Could anyone kindly let me know how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the receiver you are targeting within your own app?

Comment: No, I am getting all receivers using queryBroadcastReceivers(someCommonIntent, 0) api. I want to send Broadcast to one of those, need not be from my app.

Comment: That seems to defeat the purpose of having an ordered broadcast that is meant to be handled by the system...

Answer (score 0):

BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String CUSTOM_INTENT = "jason.wei.custom.intent.action.TEST";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("HIT OUTGOING");
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
        context.sendBroadcast(i);
    }

}
```

add this code into manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".IncomingReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="jason.wei.custom.intent.action.TEST"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Sorry, dint get your answer. you are just creating a delegate. How can you accomplish targeting a specific Receiver?
Please add some explanation, thanks.

Comment: @tekkavi Please refer this link.
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/